# php json_encode(): "Malformed UTF-8 characters" despite no unusual characters

Tags: php

I have a script which creates an array containing entries for a table that I'd like to encode as json to send to my app. Each entry is an associative array of k/v pairs of `string=>string|int`. The code to generate the full array is as follows:

```
$entries = [];
foreach($stats as $i => $stat){
    $playerStats = new Player_Stats($stat);
    $entry = [
        'place' => $i,
        'name' => $playerStats->name(),
        'elo' => $playerStats->currentRating(),
        'highest' => $playerStats->highRating(),
        'masterPoints' => $playerStats->onlineMasterPoints(),
        'winLose' => $playerStats->matchesWonLost(),
        'winRate' => $playerStats->winPercent(),
        'numEvents' => $playerStats->numEvents(),
        'wins' => $playerStats->eventsWon(),
        'placed' => $playerStats->eventsPlaced()
    ];
    $entries[] = $entry;
}
$result = json_encode($entries);
```

When I do a count or vardump etc on entries, It clearly shows that its been properly filled with the correct data. `json_encode()` returns false however. Using `json_last_error_msg()`, I get the UTF-8 error in the title: `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`. All of the other posts on this issue I could find involved characters from other languages. All of the content in this array is made of the english alphabet and numbers, all ascii characters let alone utf-8.

Am I just missing something trivial (I usually am) or should I be looking for or trying something else completely?

Comment: can you provide us the payload for which you are getting error ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the option to ignore these, `JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE` so your code would be `json_encode($data, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE);`

This will ignore invalid UTF-8 as the name describes. You can see all options for `json_encode` here. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Normally, I would agree, but in this context I would debate that the error being character encoding, you could use the ignore option on json_encode until you find the root of your issue.

Comment: This did stop the errors from occuring but it hasn't fixed the underlying issue. I have gone and traced down a single occurence of the issue and it turns out there are a couple odd characters in the data, but they're all unicode characters, this particular case being an `ñ`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the trick:

```php
$result = json_encode(array_map(utf8_encode, $entries))
```